# Programmatically ascertain aspects of socket file

Tags: proc, socket

I'm trying to write a program (in C) which, as one of its features, walks the procfs to find open sockets and ascertain things like the destination/source ports/addresses (similar to what netstat and lsof do).  However, I'm not sure which system call to use once I find a socket file.  For example, suppose I've called `readlink` on `/proc/123/fd/4` and have gotten back `socket:[56789]`.  What can I do with this information, using the system API alone, to get the socket's details?

I've tried running `strace` on `netstat` but it's not clear what's going on.  I see a `read` on `/proc/123/fdinfo/4` but I don't understand what that's all about.

For example, the `fdinfo` file for one open connection (TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5000) shows

```
pos:    0
flags:  04002
mnt_id: 9
```

Comment: Looking at the source code of `netstat` might show how it's done there.

Comment: If you were to cat out `/proc/123/fdinfo/4`, you may get a better idea of what it is all about.

Comment: Related: [Who's got the other end of this unix socketpair?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/16300). On Linux, there are some old style `/proc/net/unix`, `/proc/net/tcp`... API and there are new netlink ones. Look at the source of ss or lsof for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/pid/fdinfo/fd` gives information about attributes of the file descriptor and the open file description behind it and is documented in the [proc(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page.

It doesn't have socket-specific information.

Historically on Linux, information about sockets could be obtained from text files in `/proc/net`, one for each address family and protocol (like `/proc/net/unix`, `/proc/net/udp6`...).

But there is now an alternative *netlink* API that is more appropriate for programatic use and more reliable (in particular `/proc/net/unix` cannot be parsed reliably as it breaks with socket files with newline characters) and featureful.

That is documented in the [netlink(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) man page, and specifically for the socket diagnostics information in [sock_diag(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html) ([renamed from `inet_diag` and extended to other families in 2011](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7f1fb60c4fc9fb29fbb406ac8c4cfb4e59e168d6) itself [renamed and extended from `tcpdiag` in 2005](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=73c1f4a033675) itself added in [2.5.2.1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git//commit/?id=d694597ed5e1) in 2002) . See also info at kernel.org:

- [Netlink Intro](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/userspace-api/netlink/intro.html)
- [Netlink Handbook](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/userspace-api/netlink/index.html)

That is itself a socket-based API used by applications to talk to the kernel. Like for other sockets, you use the `socket()` system call to create the socket (with `AF_NETLINK` as the address family), some `setsockopt()`s to tune it and `sendmsg()`/`recvmsg()` to send/receive the information.

That's what `ss` (from `iproute2`) uses. While `netstat` (from `net-tools`), `lsfd` (from `util-linux`) seem to still be using the `/proc/net/...` files interface. `lsof` can also use it on Linux for its `+E` option.

Newer versions of `strace` can decode the messages sent and received on those sockets, so you can see it in action with `ss` for instance with:

```
$ strace -qqe network ss -lt
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [1048576], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_NETLINK, NETLINK_EXT_ACK, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=9352, nl_groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{nlmsg_len=72, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=0}, {sdiag_family=AF_INET, sdiag_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP, idiag_ext=0, idiag_states=1<<TCP_CLOSE|1<<TCP_LISTEN, id={idiag_sport=htons(0), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[0, 0]}}], iov_len=72}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 72
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_TRUNC}, MSG_PEEK|MSG_TRUNC) = 812
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[[{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(4330), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8331, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=5, idiag_uid=997, idiag_inode=18774}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 5094], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]], [{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(3306), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8332, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=80, idiag_uid=121, idiag_inode=4823}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 3733], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, freebind=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]], [{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(22), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8333, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=128, idiag_uid=0, idiag_inode=2707}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 3774], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]], [{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(44321), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8334, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=5, idiag_uid=0, idiag_inode=18553}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 5012], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]], [{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(44322), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8335, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=128, idiag_uid=0, idiag_inode=18613}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 5135], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]], [{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(44323), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8336, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=128, idiag_uid=0, idiag_inode=18614}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 5135], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]], [{nlmsg_len=116, nlmsg_type=SOCK_DIAG_BY_FAMILY, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=123456, nlmsg_pid=9352}, {idiag_family=AF_INET, idiag_state=TCP_LISTEN, idiag_timer=0, idiag_retrans=0, id={idiag_sport=htons(631), idiag_dport=htons(0), idiag_src=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"), idiag_dst=inet_addr("0.0.0.0"), idiag_if=0, idiag_cookie=[8337, 0]}, idiag_expires=0, idiag_rqueue=0, idiag_wqueue=4096, idiag_uid=0, idiag_inode=3811}, [[{nla_len=5, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SHUTDOWN}, 0], [{nla_len=12, nla_type=INET_DIAG_CGROUP_ID}, 3610], [{nla_len=6, nla_type=INET_DIAG_SOCKOPT}, {is_icsk=1, mc_loop=1, mc_all=1}]]]], iov_len=32768}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 812
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to read `/proc/net/tcp` which lists, for your networking namespace, the details of all open TCP/IP connections (look at `/proc/net/tcp6` for TCP/IPv6 connections).  This information includes the associated inode numbers.  An example line from that file is

```
2: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 19691 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
```

The `00000000:0016` means that the socket is listening on `0.0.0.0` port 22.  We know this is a listening socket since the peer address (`00000000:0000`) is all zeros.  We can see that the inode for this socket is 19691.

Once armed with those numbers, you can match them up with the listings in `/proc/<pid>/fd`.  For example, `socket:[12345]` means the socket is at inode 12345.  Better yet, you can call `stat` on `/proc/<pid>/fd/4` and pull the inode number from the `struct stat` object.